Inverting buck-boost PWM design and error amplifier question
I am trying to figure out how to put together an inverting buck-boost converter using SG1524 (SG3524). The required output is -6 V @ 200 mA. Input voltage is 12 V.
The reference design is available in one of the reference books I have.

Unfortunately this design is not present in any datasheets that I came across.
How are R1 and R2 values selected? Based on the other schematics I've seen I would expect R1=500 Ω and R2=100 Ω. Does someone perhaps have a practical example of this circuit?
I've also noticed some inconsistencies in SG1524 datasheets from various manufacturers regarding error amplifier biasing.
Excerpt from TI SG3524 datasheet:

Excerpt from Intersil CA3524 datasheet:

Which of these two schematics should be considered correct?
I also have at my disposal a sizable amount of very similar ICs manufactured in USSR - 1114EU1 - these are supposed to be a clone of SG3524 with some additional features.

Unfortunately it lacks positive error amplifier comparator input - which is internally connected to Vref. Would it be possible to use this part to make inverting buck-boost converter? How should the error amplifier be biased in this case?
I would really appreciate your help!

Have you tried using a simulator to figure out decent values for the two resistors?

Welcome to the wild world of appnotes, where review is minimal and citations are lacking. Have you tried asking TI? They have a forum at e2e.ti.com

@Andyaka the values 500 and 100 I've mentioned were taken from this book. On page 1196 of the pdf file they are discussing a comparator based converter from 5v to -15v. Adjusted for my input and output like this. This produces the following result. As for SG3524 - I haven't found it's spice model online. I am not sure how R1 and R2 should be selected.
